# How does one include just the node binary in a python buildpack?

Tags: node.js, heroku, buildpack

We're running a python app sharing some code between our client and server by having one component being written in node.

What is the easiest way to have node installed in a python buildpack ?

There is a 3rd party buildpack that I've forked that I'm using to do this so that we can access the node binary.

I would ideally want to stick to just the officially buildpacks as much as possible.
My question is if there is a less intrusive way to have just install node and nothing else.

Comment: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi could be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This buildpack lets you run both node and python:

https://github.com/ayyar/heroku-buildpack-python-nodejs.git

( It's forked from https://github.com/fivethreeo/heroku-buildpack-python-nodejs, though I ran into some bugs which I fixed )